# Prove that a ring does not have a multiplicative identity

Tags: matrices

Let $R =$ the set of all matrices $
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
x & 0 \\
y & 0 \\
    \end{array}
\right]
 $ where $x, y \in \mathbb Z$ with R being a ring under matrix addition and multiplication.

Prove that R does not have a multiplicative identity.

I think I am making this out to be harder than it really is. It doesn't have an identity because

$$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
    \end{array}
\right]$$

is not in R, correct?

Comment: Is it ordinary matrix multiplication, or is there a different kind of multiplication on $R$?

Comment: How are $a,b$ related to $R$ ?

Comment: Presumably regular matrix multiplication, not Hadamard multiplication.  For starters, your notation is all messed up.  You refer to $R$ equalling a specific matrix with entries $x,0,y$ and $0$, and then you refer to $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.  What are $a$ and $b$ and what do they have to do with $R$?  Presumably you mean $R = \{\begin{bmatrix} x & 0 \\ y & 0\end{bmatrix} ~:~x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.  Note that simply not having the usual identity matrix isn't enough since $S = \{\begin{bmatrix} x & 0\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}~:~x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ has multiplicative identity $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, sorry, mistyped the variables, updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're logic is not quite correct; note that 
$$
\left\{ \pmatrix{x&0\\0&0}: x \in \Bbb Z \right\}
$$
forms a ring under the usual matrix multiplication and *has* an identity element.

---

**Hint:** There is no $A$ in $R$ such that $AB = B$, where
$$
B = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}
$$